# adding objects from an ArrayList to another ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();


public void addScore( String name, int value){
    Score temp  = new Score();
    temp.playerName = name;
    temp.value = value;
    scores.add(temp);
    Collections.sort(scores, new Comparator<Score>() {
        public int compare(Score o1, Score o2) {
            return (o1.value - o2.value);
        }
    });

public ArrayList<Score> getTopScores(int number){
    ArrayList<Score> topScores = new ArrayList<Score>();
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i<=number;i++){
            topScores.add(scores[i]);
            return topScores;
        }
```

So basically i'm trying to return an array that grabs (number) of Scores from the scores ArrayList.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i<=number;i++){
            topScores.add(scores[i]);
            return topScores;
        }` you should put the `return` statement out of the loop

Comment: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Score>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a ArrayList elements in a manner fit for an array.

This of course will never work.

Use `scores.get(i)`

If you simply want to get a range of elements as a `List` use the [subList(int fromIndex,int toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method in java List API without doing manual splitting.

Comment: thanks used topScores.add(scores.get(i)); and it worked, thanks for clarifying the difference between Array and ArrayLists.